# Use program parameters for graph drawing - TI92+

Tags: variables, graph, ti-basic

I have a problem with a program on my TI92+.
It does work without a problem on a TI92, though.
I want to draw a graph, that I enter as a program argument, e.g. test(x^2)
Program goes like this:

```
test(var1)
Prgm
var1->k
k->y1(x)
ZoomStd
setMode("split 1 app","graph"):Pause
EndPrgm
```

On the TI92 it shows me a simple x^2 function, on the TI92+ I get "Undefined Variable" as an error message. Interestingly enough, when I enter "k" on the home screen, I get x^2 as an output. So the variable is there.
I am in the main folder and this happens with a reset calculator as well.
I understand that TI changed something about the variables between TI92 and TI92+, you can have local variables, but this is no local variable.
And finally: this is just a test program I am using to demonstrate my problem, of course I know I could just type x^2 into the y= editor and hey presto. But a program I have written years ago doesn't work and I would like to know, why and where I have to change something.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the Y= Editor, does it display `y1=k`? On my TI-89 Titanium (which I understand uses similar software), `k→y1(x)` literally stores `k` to `y1`. This is a problem since it tries to substitute all instances of `x` in `y1` (of which there are none) with the value passed to `y1`. Then, since `k` is an expression type, not a number, the calculator refuses to graph it. I'm still trying to find a work around for this.